# HTMLUnit Java, only works sometimes

Tags: java, testing, htmlunit

I am using `HTMLUnit` in java to navigate a website. First it logs on and then navigates to a page.

Sometimes I run it and it works fine. However other times when I run it it just stops on the same messages on the console without any changes to the code.
I've found it so hard to work this one out.

The message the console usually stops on is:

```
htmlunit.incorrectnessListnerImpl notify
Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'
htmlunit.incorrectnessListnerImpl notify
Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'
```

I though it could be a problem with it not waiting for `AJAX` calls to execute, however I have tried setting the web client to use the `NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController` and `waitforbackgroundjavascript`, but still get the same problem.

If anyone has any ideas I would be very grateful!